# Concatenation and looping through Checkboxes & Boolean values

Tags: excel, vba

Below code pulls the values from 10 checkboxes and applies a respective Boolean check.

I'm struggling with concatenating the checkbox and Boolean names into a While loop. Anyone assist please?

```
If CheckD1.Value = True Then check1 = True
If CheckD2.Value = True Then check2 = True
If CheckD3.Value = True Then check3 = True
If CheckD4.Value = True Then check4 = True
If CheckD5.Value = True Then check5 = True
If CheckD6.Value = True Then check6 = True
If CheckD7.Value = True Then check7 = True
If CheckD8.Value = True Then check8 = True
If CheckD9.Value = True Then check9 = True
If CheckD10.Value = True Then check10 = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an array `Check(1 To 10)` instead of individual variables `check1 … check10` and something like `UserForm1.Controls` to access your checkboxes by a variable name:

```
Dim Check(1 To 10) As Boolean

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 10
    Check(i) = UserForm1.Controls("CheckD" & i).Value
Next i
```

`UserForm1` is the form your checkboxes `CheckD1` to `CheckD10` are in.

If you used Form Controls on a worksheet then it should be

```
Check(i) = (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("CheckD" & i).OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1)
```

Comment: Thank you! Beat me to it by a snip, but glad to see I went down the right route in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Worked it out myself in the end, so posting the answer for others if they need.

Declared my check Booleans as an array with:

```
Dim check(1 to 10) as Boolean
```

Then looped through the checkboxes on the UserForm with:

```
For i = 1 To 10

If Me.Controls("CheckD" & i).Value = True Then
    check(i) = True
End If

Next I
```

Simple for those that know, but something new learnt for today!